# Benchmark positive thinking within Stack Exchange communities

Tags: discussion, statistics

Is it possible to use the Stack Exchange API to somehow calculate the average up to down voting ratio, and vote to question / answer ratio on different Stack Exchange sites?

Could this info be used to prove once and for all that Christians are, or are not Happy Clappy, and Politicians are (or are not - yeah right) cynical?

Comment: Yeah, you can do this with the data explorer: http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: Happy Clappy?  That's a new one... had to look that one up.

Comment: You do realize that not all users on Christianity are Christians, not all users on Politics are politicians and not all users on Super User are super, right?

Comment: Here's an example query (for SO) which may contain some information on what you want. Copy the query into whatever community you want, and then analyze: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/110307/average-ratio-of-up-to-down-votes

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII "Integer Division", SCNR. :)

Comment: That data explorer is excellent! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The Jewish community seems quite friendly: http://data.stackexchange.com/jewish%20life%20and%20learning/query/110307/average-ratio-of-up-to-down-votes :)

Comment: @BillyMoon just be careful, that query was quick, and it only uses integer division (causing truncation).

Comment: @BillyMoon this query is arguably better, as it uses floating point math, and eliminates users who haven't both up and down voted: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/110317

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII thanks - that is spot on!

Answer (score 11):

Since you don't really know the vast majority of sociological data about answerers, it would be impossible to extrapolate any trends. Even if you did, it would hardly constitute "proof".

Comment: So you are saying that people on the Christianity site are not necessarily christians - and therefore the data would be inaccurate right? I think it would hold for some sites, like I expect only gamers go on that site, and only programmers go to stack overflow.

Comment: @BillyMoon Correct. I've seen people active on multiple religion sites. Certainly they can't believe in all of them no?

Comment: It is a fair point, but I would hope that you can assume (or through some other means ascertain) a weighting towards the topic of the site. I would be surprised if there was not a higher percentage of Christians on their SE site than in Cooking SE for example.

Comment: Proof is roughly defined as something that reinforces my existing beliefs

Answer (score 4):

I'm a physics student. I'm not:

- a programmer
- an ethical hacker
- Anything that has to do with chemistry
- Anything that has to do with robotics
- an electrical engineer

yet I have [a good amount of rep](https://stackexchange.com/users/1212053/manishearth?tab=accounts) on those sites. Take a look at [Rory Alsop](https://stackexchange.com/users/251740/rory-alsop?tab=accounts) and [Gilles](https://stackexchange.com/users/164368/gilles?tab=accounts) as well.

Similarly, people on Christianity.SE are not necessarily Christians. There are a lot of folks who are active on multiple religion sites (the mods of these sites are a good example)

People on Politics are not necessarily politicians.

The sites have some experts and a lot of *enthusiasts*. There are enthusiasts who know a good amount of stuff about the topic, and there are enthusiasts who are just interested in learning. This means that the type of person varies a lot, regardless of rep.

You'd be measuring apples here and labeling them as oranges.

---

However, take a look at [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/110317) (you can compose your own if you wish).

Comment: Is there an `ethical hacking` SE site?

Comment: So - what you are saying is that I need quite a complex query that ignores people who subscribe to competing sites?

Comment: Do you accept that there is probably a higher ratio of programmers on stack overflow than photography SE? It does not have to be that 100% are programmers, just a higher ratio, as I am only looking for trends.

Comment: @BillyMoon: [security.se]. re:complex query: no, that wouldn't work either. I have plenty of non-physicists active on Physics.SE only. My point was that the most you can say about a person with rep on a site is that 'they are interested in the topic". For high reps you can say "they know a bit about the topic". Nothing more. And, FYI: iirc _very few_ of the users on [politics.se] are politicians.

Comment: And keep in mind that a large portion of the users on other sites might well be the developers on SO who were aware of the wider SE network.

Comment: @Bart: yeah, that's usually the case

Comment: Your SEDE link is broken...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Fixed, thanks :)